# Perl getting syntax error in if-statement

Tags: perl

I get a couple of syntax errors when trying to use an if-statement.

This is my code:

```
    use warnings; 
    use LWP::Simple;
    use POSIX;

    my $dtime = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', gmtime(1593953411))

    if ($dtime->day_of_week == 7 || $dtime->day_of_week == 6){
        $total_between_time = $total_between_time - $dayinsec
    }
    else{
        if (($time1+($i*$dayinsec)) + $dayinsec > $time2){
            print "beggining: ", $time1+$i*$dayinsec, " end: ", $time2, "\n";
        }
        else{
            print "beggining: ", $time1+$i*$dayinsec, " end: ", ($time1+($i*$dayinsec)) + $dayinsec, "\n";
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
syntax error at ovning2.pl line 30, near "){"
syntax error at ovning2.pl line 33, near "else"
```

Why am I getting these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of the line before your `if` statement.  Fixed:

```
my $dtime = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', gmtime(1593953411));
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is not with `if` condition.

There is a semicolon missing in `my $dtime = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', gmtime(1593953411))` line.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have 33 lines in your sample code, so those errors are from something else.

When you get errors, remember that the error is from the point that Perl got confused. The error has already happened. Look at the line before the error number:

When you can't track down these problems, start bisecting your code. You may start with this, and see that it works:

```
use warnings; 
use LWP::Simple;
use POSIX;

my $dtime = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', gmtime(1593953411))
__END__
... rest of program
```

Then, add a little more, and you discover an error. Now you have a target to investigate:

```
...
my $dtime = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', gmtime(1593953411))

if ($dtime->day_of_week == 7 || $dtime->day_of_week == 6){
    $total_between_time = $total_between_time - $dayinsec
}
__END__
```

Maybe you still don't see it, so play with that little bit:

```
...
my $dtime = strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', gmtime(1593953411))

if (1){1}
__END__
```

Continue in this manner so in each step you convince yourself that something is not the problem.